# How does ItemsControl.ItemsSource bind from something that doesn't implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, wpf

[ItemsControl.ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource) is `IEnumerable`. [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable) isn't `IEnumerable`. I would expect `DataTable` to fail to bind to `ItemsSource`. Yet, the code below works. Why?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"/>
```

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

public DataTable Table { get; set; } = new DataTable();
```

When I set `ItemsSource` to `DataTable` without binding, it fails like I would expect. However, casting `DataTable` to `IEnumerable<DataRowView>` compiles without error.

```
new DataGrid().ItemsSource = new DataTable(); // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
new DataGrid().ItemsSource = (IEnumerable<DataRowView>)new DataTable(); // compiles without error
```

Does binding cast `DataTable` to `IEnumerable<DataRowView>`? Where is the documentation for this behavior? I would expect the `ItemsSource` documentation to explain this casting, but I don't see anything there.

Comment: Your second line will throw `InvalidCastException` at runtime but will compile without error as you said.

Comment: If you follow the inheritance chain, you will see a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>`, so through binding they can get to what is needed (explicitly). Obviously, there is no implicit conversion.

Comment: @insane_developer Where is that? There isn't anything like that in the DataTable declaration.

Comment: If you look at the IListSource interface, which DataTable implements, it has a method with this signature: `public System.Collections.IList GetList ();`  An IList can be bound to a data source from the object. My previous comment mentions a generic interface, which is a mistake.

Comment: @insane_developer Sure, and there is also the AsEnumerable extension method in DataTable. Still, both does not answer the question: How exactly is the conversion done by a Binding?

Comment: @Clemens for that you would have to look at the framework's code, or maybe somebody else already looked at it and can say for sure. For me it's enough to know that there is a way to do it and there is no magic going on.

Comment: @insane_developer Then you are totally ignoring the fact that there actually is magic going on. As you have realized yourself, no implicit conversion exists. And no TypeConverter is registered. And honestly, "*for me it's enough*" isn't really helpful for others, I suppose.

Comment: I was looking at the source and there is a type converter on the `IListSource` interface.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/IListSource.cs,52b4f37b14110019

Comment: I just did some more digging and that ValueConverter was for design view. There is however code to handle this case in the WPF DefaultValueConverter -https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/DefaultValueConverter.cs,49c30fec261b0516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the cast to `IEnumerable<DataRowView>` does not work. It compiles, but will throw at runtime:
[image]

The binding works for `DataTable` because it implements `IListSource`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ilistsource?view=netcore-3.1

This interface is explicitly accounted for in the WPF `DefaultValueConverter`

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/DefaultValueConverter.cs,49c30fec261b0516

```cs
// special case for converting IListSource to IList
if (typeof(IListSource).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType) &&
                targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList)))
{
    return new ListSourceConverter();
}
```

And the default converter is created with the binding

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpression.cs,444

```cs
IValueConverter converter = Engine.GetDefaultValueConverter(type, TargetProperty.PropertyType, IsReflective);
```